# How to fix Wordpress 404 moving from Apache to Nginx (Vesta)?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, nginx

Hi :) I have some Wordpress sites, trying to move them from shared hosting to VPS. First site moved without any problems, still [next site](https://ecobig.ru) gives complete 404. It doesn't matter what base credentials I use (no 'connect to database' problem), just no reaction. It still can see some static files inside directory (like robots.txt).

My main concern is htaccess settings. On shared server I used some custom setting for redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^(s-stat) - [L]
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.ecobig\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://ecobig.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-HTTPS} !1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Moving to nginx (VestaCP) I deleted htaccess files, hoping it'll just work and I adjust redirect later. Still no signals of life from site.

What I need to do? Fix some nginx conf, or add redirects, or disable all plugins, before transfering? Any idea is valuable :) Also, I said before, I've moved 1 non-https site to VPN already and it works great, so https can be an issue.

**Specs:**
Ubuntu 16.04
VestaCP
VestaCP wordpress2 and socket profiles
Let's Encrypt certificate generated, works good for non-https (now it's https) site I moved before

Comment: Logs full of "permission denied" (http://i.imgur.com/9PjaleP.png)

Comment: Used chmod 755 on web, web/ecobig.ru, web/ecobig.ru/public_html directories, no effect

Comment: Used chmod 755 on index.php, got first database connection error :) Use right credentials, now have 500 error main page. Great)

Comment: I'll try to recreate Vesta project, maybe it helps.

Comment: Fixed permissions fir chmods, Allowed memory error received (http://i.imgur.com/gogKQVH.png). Upgraded memory usage to 512 mb, no real change.

Comment: Upgraded usage to 2048 mb, site works, but really slow. Site from shared hosting can't eat 2048 mb, it works for years with 256 mb max. Miracles.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to do some changes to the nginx.conf file in order to add the same redirects to https like you had before.

Now, about the "permission denied" errors, check if the user account that is used to run nginx has access to **/home/admin/web/ecobig.ru/** and below.

Comment: I had no issues with similar Wordpress site, using same Vesta config etc. hour ago, so all permissions must be done by Vesta correctly. Can't chmod every file, quite useless.

Comment: Maybe I must use "sudo unzip" or smth to copy Wordpress files to public_html, but it looks like madness :)